# javascript variable not defined when inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework, twirl

**Background:**

I am using [PlayFramework](https://www.playframework.com/) to create a webapp (workflow) system which uses the [Twirl template engine](http://scalatra.org/guides/2.4/views/twirl.html) (scala based) to create my views.

**Problem:**

I need to store JavaScript variables inside of my template (which renders HTML), where in a separate JS file(s), I will perform operations on later.

**Any existing solutions?**

This can be done according to these **SO** questions I found:

1. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693562/playframework-html-variable-into-javascript) creates a map where data is stored in and later retrieved.
2. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157203/play-framework-twirl-template-comparing-javascript-element-and-scala-variable) creates a simple example of storing a variable in an inline script tag to use later
3. Finally, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096229/using-javascript-in-play-template) uses a more concrete example of storing data in data structures in the template and accessing the data structures in JS after being parsed.

*The example created by an active SO contributor, [Biesior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066240/biesior), helping many developers with Play! Framework questions*

**To summarise what *should* be done:**

1. Pass in some data into template

```js
@(myData: DataObject)
```

2. Add data passed in an into a script tag with a JS name

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      let someJSDataName = @myData
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. Use in JS / Google Chrome Dev console

```js
someJSDataName.toString
```

This *should* display some result!

**But what is the problem?**

Let me show you.

Rendered Html:

```
//...
<div class="BoxMediumBlue" style="padding: 20px;">

        <script>
                let facultyDepartments = {Science=[Computer Science, Physics], Biology=[Zooology]};
        </script>

        <br>
        <div class="container-heading">
//...
```

When attempting to access this data in my Google Chrome dev console:

```
facultyDepartments
VM1209:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: facultyDepartments is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Just an FYI, using `var` makes no difference

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your rendered HTML's JS's syntax is invalid. `= {Science=[Computer Science, Physics],...`

Comment: This should represent a JS map. How is it invalid (I cannot see the problem)

Comment: A JS Map would involve `new Map(...` somewhere. If you meant to have an object, objects need key-value pairs, where the key and value are separated by `:`s, and each pair is separated by `,`. String values also need delimiters.

Comment: Hmmm. I believe a JSON parser can help me with this. Thank you, would you mind posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `facultyDepartments` uses syntax that the JS engine doesn't understand:

```js
let facultyDepartments = {Science=[Computer Science, Physics], Biology=[Zooology]};
```

Objects should contain key-value pairs, where the keys and values are separated by `:`s, and where the keys and values, when strings, have delimiters like `"` or `'`. You should try to get the template to render JSON instead, for example:

```js
let facultyDepartments = {"Science":["Computer Science", "Physics"], "Biology":["Zooology"]};
console.log(facultyDepartments.Science);
```

(JSON is technically a way of formatting *strings*, but inserting a JSON string without delimiters so that it's parsed as an object literal works too)